# Allow access to all files from a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to allow access to all files from a subfolder with htaccess file.

I found many examples about 'how to deny', but each time it explains a part of the thing.

There's the file's content I created (but it doesn't work):

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
```

The file is located in the folder.

And that is for the .htaccess file located in root :

```
# Omeka .htaccess: Apache configuration file
# This file is required for Omeka to function correctly.

# --------------- #
# Error Reporting #
# --------------- #

# Uncomment the SetEnv line below to turn on detailed on-screen error
# reporting.
#
# Note: This should only be enabled for development or debugging. Keep this
# line commented for production sites.
# 
# SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

# ------------- #
# Rewrite Rules #
# ------------- #

RewriteEngine on

# If you know mod_rewrite is enabled, but you are still getting mod_rewrite
# errors, uncomment the line below and replace "/" with your base directory.
#
# RewriteBase /

# Allow direct access to files (except PHP files)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule !\.(php[0-9]?|phtml|phps)$ - [C]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^install/.*$ install/install.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ admin/index.php [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php

# -------------- #
# Access Control #
# -------------- #

# Block access to all .ini files.
<FilesMatch "\.ini$">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# --------#
# Caching #
# --------#

# Uncomment the lines below in order to enable caching of some files
# (after a finished site has gone live)
#
# <IfModule mod_expires.c>
#    <FilesMatch "\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$">
#        ExpiresActive on
#        ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 day"
#    </FilesMatch>
# </IfModule>

# ------------ #
# PHP Settings #
# ------------ #

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag register_globals off
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
</IfModule>
```

What is missing please?

Comment: Looks like you've combined both Apache 2.2 and 2.4 methods into one. What version of Apache are you running?

Comment: This is version 2.2